# Spring's MapJobRegistry no setters found for properties dataSource and tablePrefix

Tags: xml, spring-batch

I am currently following the instructions stated in the [Spring Batch Documentation Section 1.6.2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/job.html#jobregistry) to create a `jobRegistry` bean using  XML. I followed it exactly and put the below code into my XML file:

```
<bean id="jobRegistry" 
 class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" 
 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:tablePrefix="BATCH_"/>
```

But the problem is that Eclipse IDE keeps showing errors as shown below:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>
> - No setter found for property 'dataSource' in class     'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry'
> - No setter found for property 'tablePrefix' in class    'org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry'

When I go and check the [API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/support/MapJobRegistry.html) for the `MapJobRegistry` class, it indeed has no setter for those properties. If that's the case, what is the correct way of creating the `jobRegistry` bean?

My project is using `spring-core 5.0.0.RELEASE` and `spring-batch-core 4.0.0.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a JIRA ticket for that: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2669

This has been fixed and will be part of 4.0.1 release.

You can remove these two properties from the bean declaration and it should be fine.

Hope this helps.